# Data structure for representing segments of numbers

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, data-structures

I have set of objects and each of them has several 6-octet addresses (like aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.fff). Possible addresses of each object represented in ranges. I need to be able to search object by address and by mask (e.g. aaa.bbb.ccc.*.eee.fff). What is the most suitable data structure for this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your application, you can use a binary search tree or a trie.
For example in a trie, you search until you reach the mask. then you need to iterate over all the children of the node with mask. And perform the rest of the search on them.